# Scss url use of alias in Webpack with storybook

Tags: javascript, webpack, storybook

I am creating a component library (an npm package that has a storybook instance, but mostly is just a library of re-exported components to be used in several other applications). As such, I have a storybook configuration, but also a way to build the library using a standalone webpack configuration. This standalone webpack configuration *seems* to work ok (it builds... I haven't gotten further than that yet, hah), but one of the issues is that when I import font files in my *scss* styles, I need to associate an alias so that they resolve to a directory that is at the root of the source filesystem.

I have the following file system setup:

```
aegir/
  - src/
  - assets/
    - fonts/
      - fontfiles...
    - styles/ // Shared scss files among different components
      - Typography.scss 
  - components/
    - 01-Atoms/
      - EditableRecipeTitle.js
      - EditableRecipeTitle.scss // Component-specific scss files
```

I define a Webpack configuration in `storybook/main.js` as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app"
  ],

  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({})
    config.resolve.alias = {
      '@Assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/')
    };

    return config;
  }
}
```

As you can see, this defines an `@Assets` alias that I intend to use as follows, for example, in `Typography.scss`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Work Sans";
  src: url("@Assets/fonts/WorkSans-Regular.ttf");
}
```

This appears to work for the *library* webpack configuration, which looks like the following:

```
const path = require('path')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'aegir',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@Assets": path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
     {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif|woff|eot|woff2|ttf)$/i,
        use: [ 'url-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

That is to say, `yarn build` generates a packaged `dist/index.js` file, and I can see that *some* fonts are being bundled (although the WorkSans-Regular.ttf doesn't appear to be among these... Perhaps this is a clue as to what is wrong?)

```
$ webpack --config webpack.library.config.js
Hash: 3ce021b06e7683688699
Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 857ms
Built at: 12/30/2020 10:20:47 AM
   Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  3.39 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = index.js
[./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/components/01-Atoms/EditableRecipeTitle.scss] 44 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js] 2.46 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js] 830 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot] 216 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0] 216 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0] 579 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0] 216 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0] 101 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0] 128 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js] 70.5 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js] 6.67 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/components/01-Atoms/EditableRecipeTitle.js] 2.64 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/components/01-Atoms/EditableRecipeTitle.scss] 592 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/index.js] 158 bytes {main} [built]
    + 7 hidden modules
Done in 2.00s.
```

When I run `yarn start` (which is the command I've used to start storybook), I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/01-Atoms/EditableRecipeTitle.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--9-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-6-4!./src/components/01-Atoms/EditableRecipeTitle.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/styles/@Assets/fonts/WorkSans-Regular.ttf' in '/home/scottj/Source/aegir/src/components/01-Atoms'
    at doResolve (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:209:21)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn43 (eval at create (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn1 (eval at create (/home/scottj/Source/aegir/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
 @ ./src/components/01-Atoms/EditableRecipeTitle.scss 2:26-319 53:4-74:5 56:18-311
 @ ./src/components/01-Atoms/EditableRecipeTitle.js
 @ ./src/stories/01-Atoms/EditableRecipeTitle.stories.js
 @ ./src sync ^\.(?:(?:^|\/|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|\/)\.).)*?)\/)(?!\.)(?=.)[^\/]*?\.stories\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))$
 @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
```

I'm wondering if the `resolve-url-loader` might be messing things up in the pipeline. Any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Comment: You need to add the missing url rewriting using the `resolve-url-loader`. Place it before `sass-loader` in the loader chain. Check [problem-with-url](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/10990#issuecomment-778658549).